# Can this be vectorized with numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

I have this function, and I was wondering if there was a way to vectorize it, as I am running many loops over this and it becomes pretty slow.  w, x, y, z, and n are constants, and input_vec is a vector of length n

```
def calc_v(w, x, y, z, input_vec, n):

    v = np.empty(n)

    v[0] = 1

    for i in range(1, n):
        past_v = v[i - 1]
        past_input = input_vec[i - 1]

        # UCL
        part1 = (1 / past_v) * (x * (y - past_v) - ((w*w) / 2)) * z
        part2 = w * (1 / math.sqrt(past_v)) * math.sqrt(z) * past_input

        v[i] = past_v * exp(part1 + part2)

    return v
```

Comment: Might be hard to vectorize given the dependency, but maybe `numba` can help alongwith pre-computing of few terms like `math.sqrt(z)`, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't give me the speed up I need.  If it can't be vectorized, I'll need to port this to C++ to use vectors

Comment: Well `numba` is basically C (performance-wise close to it). So, take a look there.

Comment: Numba definitely makes this function faster, thanks!

Comment: you could probably rewrite it in `numpy` but you would use approximately three times the memory of this code, by precalculating `partial1` and `partial2`. If you need it (and provide some test input and output), I might give it a try.